# Ansible Galaxy collection dependency SSH error with private GitHub repo

Tags: github, ssh, ansible, ansible-galaxy, ansible-collections

Being new to Ansible collections I’m hoping I’ve missed something obvious here in my attempt to refactor some old Ansible roles into collections using private GitHub repositories.

I have GitHub setup with 2 linked accounts. I’ll call the main personal account `GITHUB_AC_P`. The personal account is linked to a child organizational account I’ll call `GITHUB_AC_O`. I can switch between these accounts in the GitHub web UI and use the following single entry in `~/.ssh/config`  to access both accounts with git clients:

```
Host GITHUB_AC_P.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github_REDACTED_GITHUB_A
```

I first added Ansible Galaxy collection files to a new GitHub repository named `ansible.common` in account `GITHUB_AC_O`. I plan to reuse this collection in other Ansible Galaxy collections. It currently has a single role and the following `galaxy.yml` file:

```
namespace: REDACTED_NS
name: common
version: 0.0.1
description: "Common Ansible collection"
readme: README.md
authors:
  - REDACTED_AUTHOR
```

The following command reports  “installed successfully” and I see the collection in `~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/REDACTED_NS/common`:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install git@GITHUB_AC_P.github.com:GITHUB_AC_O/ansible.common.git,main
```

I then created a second Ansible Galaxy collection in a new GitHub repository named `ansible.harden_host`. This is also in account `GITHUB_AC_O`. This currently has no roles and uses the following `galaxy.yml` file to reference the above common collection (the value of REDACTED_NS is the same in both galaxy.yml files):

```
namespace: REDACTED_NS
name: harden_host
version: 0.0.1
description: "Ansible collection to harden hosts"
readme: README.md
authors:
  - REDACTED_AUTHOR
dependencies: {
  REDACTED_NS.common: git@GITHUB_AC_P.github.com:GITHUB_AC_O/ansible.common.git,main
}
```

But when I run the following:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install --verbose git@GITHUB_AC_P.github.com:GITHUB_AC_O/ansible.harden_host.git,main
```

It fails with message:

```
Starting galaxy collection install process
Process install dependency map
ERROR! Unknown error when attempting to call Galaxy at 'https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/': <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>
```

Why is this trying to hit `galaxy.ansible.com` instead of my GitHub account?

When I add `--ignore-certs` and run the following:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install --ignore-certs git@GUTHUB_AC_P.github.com:GITHUB_AC_O/ansible.harden_host.git,main
```

It fails with this different message:

```
ERROR! Failed to find collection REDACTED_NS.common:git@GITHUB_AC_P.github.com:GITHUB_AC_O/ansible.common.git
```

I pasted the URI from this error (right of the colon) into a `ansible-galaxy collection install` command to verify there’s no typo in the URI. This worked fine.

The string REDACTED_NS does not equal the value of GITHUB_AC_P or GITHUB_AC_O.

If someone could please explain what’s wrong here and how the issue can be fixed that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved; it seems the answer was hiding in plain site in Ansible's [Using collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository) document, which says to use the following form for git based dependencies:

```
dependencies: {'git@github.com:organization/repo_name.git': 'devel'}
```

The form I was using was for Galaxy servers, hence it was hitting `galaxy.ansible.com` (unless I overrode the default with e.g. `--server localhost`).

So the following form works (git repo followed by git reference):

```
namespace: REDACTED_NS
name: harden_host
version: 0.0.1
description: "Ansible collection to harden hosts"
readme: README.md
authors:
  - REDACTED_AUTHOR
dependencies: {
  'git@GITHUB_AC_P.github.com:GITHUB_AC_O/ansible.common.git': 'main'
}
```